# php regex name cant be longer than 50 letters how to do it?

Tags: php

I am trying to do validation on forms so if name is longer than 50 characters it will show error message.

```
if (empty($_POST['names']) || !preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $_POST['names'])) {
    $validation[] = "Name has to start with uppercase";
}

if (!preg_match('/[a-z].{50,}/', $_POST['names'])) {
    $validation[] = "Name can't be longer than 50 characters";
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: Your first regex has to be ```!preg_match('/^[A-Z]/', $_POST['names']))``` notice the `^` character. It simply means _the begining of the string_. Without it a name like `joHn` will pass the validation.

Comment: If name must start with uppercase, it will never match the second regexp as it starts with lowercase [a-z] (and as other pointed out you need the '^' to mean "starts with"

Comment: In frist regexp, the empty() check is useless because it if it is empty it will fail the second check (which should be /^[A-Z]/)

Answer (score 0):

You have `strlen` function to count the number of letters. No need for regex.

```
if (strlen($_POST['names']) > 50) {
    $validation[] = "Name can't be longer than 50 characters";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Important to note: `\strlen()` (which is the same as `\mb_strlen($message, '8bit')`) will not count the amount of characters, but the *size* of the string in bytes.

You have to distinguish between the technical maximum size in bytes (e.g. because of the limit in the database) and the actual character limit. For instance, the 'ü' in the German lastname *Müller* is a multi-byte character, so *Müller* will have a size of 7 bytes, but is only 6 characters long, so you may also want to use `\mb_strlen()` and set the internal encoding to UTF-8 using `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')`;.